# Angularjs: use ".then" and get response

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, http

I want send a http request and get response of this request. I want if data is save, I get database information and if doesn't save, I get errors. For this, I want use `.then` in angularjs. I create angularjs controller and services to do this. I have below code in angularjs part:

`bolouk.js`:

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('app');
app.controller('BoloukCtrl', ['$scope', 'Bolouks', function($scope, Bolouks){
$scope.save = function(){
        Bolouks.create($scope.bolouk).then(function(data){
        $scope.saveBolouk = data;
        },function(err){
                $scope.err = err;
            }
        );
    };
}]);
```

`boloukService.js`:

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('boloukService', ['ngResource']);
app.factory('Bolouks', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/bolouks.json', {}, {
        create: { method: 'POST', isArray: false }
    });
});
```

and I have below code in rails server:
`bolouks_controller.rb`:

```
  def create
    @bolouk = Bolouk.create(bolouk_params)
    if @bolouk.valid?
      #@bolouk.save
      respond_with @bolouk, :location => api_bolouks_path
    else
      respond_with @bolouk.errors, :location => api_bolouks_path
    end
  end
  private
  def bolouk_params
    params.require(:bolouk).permit(:boloukcode, :north, :south, :east, :west)
  end
```

Request send to rails server correctly and data is save to database right, but I cannot get response of request and when I run function`, I get below error in chrome console:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Scope.$scope.save (http://localhost:3000/assets/controllers/bolouk.js?body=1:19:39)
    at http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:10973:21
    at http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:20088:17
    at Scope.$eval (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:12752:28)
    at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:12850:23)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:20087:21)
    at HTMLFormElement.jQuery.event.dispatch (http://localhost:3000/assets/templates/jquery-1.10.2.js?body=1:4627:9)
    at HTMLFormElement.elemData.handle (http://localhost:3000/assets/templates/jquery-1.10.2.js?body=1:4295:46)
```

I think I don't use `.then` correctly in angularjs controller, I check `$q` method too, but again get this error. Any one have idea to solve this problem?

Comment: I can see that you are using $resource. So with that you can use all call back functions. Just go through this docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource 
$promise is one way where you can use .then, you need to define it within your service. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have assign both module in same variable. this may conflict your code. so use this code:

bolouk.js:

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('app',['ngResource']);
app.controller('BoloukCtrl', ['$scope', 'Bolouks', function($scope, Bolouks){
$scope.save = function(){
        Bolouks.create($scope.bolouk).$promise.then(function(data){
        $scope.saveBolouk = data;
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          console.log(err);

      })
    };
}]);
```

boloukService.js:

```
'use strict';

app.factory('Bolouks', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/bolouks.json', {}, {
        create: { method: 'POST', isArray: false }
    });
});
```

Comment: what's diffrent between your answer and my question? I add `ngResources` in `main.js` file and I can use it in `bolouk.js` and if I add this again to controller, I get error.

Comment: you have created 2 module "app" and "boloukService". and both module you are assigning in to same variable  var app. so it conflict the code or override the previous app module.

Comment: `app` is the root of angularjs controller and I have to define to all dependency. and I cannot remove the first line of `bolokService.js`, because I define the name of service in this line and use in `app.js`.

Comment: var app=angular.module('boloukService', ['ngResource']); means you are creating a module and reference them in app variable. and
 var app =angular.module('app'); means you are using existing module name is app. and again you arr referncing in var app. and we know that app is a global variable not local, so in one variable you are referencing two module.it override your code

Comment: did you use this code. could you please tell me which error you are getting using this code

Comment: When I remove first line from `boloukService.js`, porject isn't run and  I get below error in chrome console: `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: SessionProvider <- Session`

Comment: i think it your session error.you have injected session dependency.remove that one and chck

Comment: @Munkund Your answer is right, I use your answer wrong. But now I have a question, when data is save to database, I can recieve response, but when data cannot save, I don't recieve errors. Do you know why?

Comment: use edited code. i have not mentioned catch block. now i mentioned it.
now it will throw error.if you get this please inform me.

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = angular.module('app',['boloukService']);


app.controller('BoloukCtrl', ['$scope', 'Bolouks', function($scope, Bolouks){
    $scope.save = function(){
        var user = Bolouks.get();
        user.get(function(resp) {
            //request successful
        }, function(err) {
            //request error
        });
    };
}]);

angular.module('boloukService', ['ngResource']);
    app.factory('Bolouks', function($resource) {
    var savedData = {}

    function get() {
        return  $resource('/api/bolouks.json', {}, {
            create: { method: 'POST', isArray: false}
        });
    }
    return {
        get: get
    }
});
```

try this one :)

Comment: I try this type of code before, by this code I can get data that save in database, but if server doesn't save data and send errors, I cannot recieve errors.

Comment: This code is not working too and I get error. but your idea is good, now I'm trying to change and use your guide. If you have another idea, please share with me. Thanks.